# How to map USB foot switch on Mac?

Tags: mac, ableton-live

I recently got a USB footswitch in hope to use it as a stop/start recording button in Ableton. When I enter the MIDI mapping part, it doesn't let me change it from B, which holds another function. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Is there is software available from the manufacturer? It might be worth a check on their website.

Failing that there are utilities like [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com) that often are able to map keys on USB devices that are otherwise unsupported on macOS. I have never used that particular bit of software but it has been around quite a while *and* it is shareware, so you can test it for free.